# Why does `yum search` can't find latest Python version?

Tags: centos, python, yum

According to `yum` documentation in centos.org, any packages can be found in all repositories using `yum search` command.

> yum search
>
> This command is used to find any packages containing the specified
>   keyword in the description, summary, packager and package name fields
>   of RPMs in all repositories.

However, I can't find latest Python 3 version with this command. May I know why?

```
[root@CentOS7 centos]# yum search python | grep 3
python-backports-lzma.x86_64 : Backport of Python 3.3's lzma module
                                           : from Python 3
python-enum34.noarch : Backport of Python 3.4 Enum
python-gssapi.x86_64 : Python Bindings for GSSAPI (RFC 2743/2744 and extensions)
python-ipaddress.noarch : Port of the python 3.3+ ipaddress module to 2.6+
python-six.noarch : Python 2 and 3 compatibility utilities
python-urllib3.noarch : Python HTTP library with thread-safe connection pooling
python-zope-interface.x86_64 : Zope 3 Interface Infrastructure
[root@CentOS7 centos]#
```

Second, Python 2.7.5 is currently available in this OS and I would like to install latest Python 3 as well.

```
[root@CentOS7 centos]# python -V
Python 2.7.5
[root@CentOS7 centos]#
```

Why can't I do that with `yum install` command?

> yum install
>
> Used to install the latest version of a package or group of packages.
>   If no package matches the specified package name(s), they are assumed
>   to be a shell glob, and any matches are then installed.

```
[root@CentOS7 centos]# yum install python3
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.usonyx.net
 * extras: centos.usonyx.net
 * updates: centos.usonyx.net
No package python3 available.
Error: Nothing to do
[root@CentOS7 centos]# 

[root@CentOS7 centos]# yum install python-3
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.usonyx.net
 * extras: centos.usonyx.net
 * updates: centos.usonyx.net
No package python-3 available.
Error: Nothing to do
[root@CentOS7 centos]#
```

**Reference:**

https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.1/Deployment_Guide/s1-yum-useful-commands.html

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-python-3-and-set-up-a-local-programming-environment-on-centos-7

Answer (score 2):

There is no official Python v3.x in the RHEL repositories. RHEL 7 is based on Python 2.7.

However RH provides newer versions of some packages through RH Software Collections:

https://access.redhat.com/support/policy/updates/rhscl

There is Python 3.3 and 3.4.

For CentOS you should be able to use SCL:

https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/